# Unhandled Rejection(Error) when trying to disconnect from Twillio Room

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

In my twillio application i'm getting random errors when tryin to disconnect from the room.

This is the code I'm trying to execute upon exit:

```
        this.log('Leaving room...');
        try {
            this.activeRoom ? this.activeRoom.disconnect().catch(console.log) : console.log('No active room to disconnect / check disconnect logic');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
```

this creates the following error:

[image: Error]

I'm not so concerned about the error itself but the fact that i cannot catch the error.
As you can see both try/catch block and .catch() were added but I'm still getting this error.

**UPDATE_1**

After digging thru the api I found and implemented this:

```
this.activeRoom.on('disconnected', function(room, error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Unexpectedly disconnected:', error);
  }
  myRoom.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(function(track) {
    track.stop();
    track.detach();
  });
});
```

however this error still comes up for me.

**UPDATE_2**

After implementing solution proposed in an answer this is what I got(still the same error):
[image]

Comment: `this.activeRoom.on('error',(err)=>{})` Try this. This may not work, but I think you need to capture the event instead.

Comment: this didnt work :(

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that runs into this issue. The stack trace you get from `room.disconnect()` is misleading.

The actual error is in your `room.localParticipant.publishTrack(track)` call. That function returns a promise, and will resolve (with an exception) the moment you call `room.disconnect()`.

If you haven't handled failure there, you'll get the error shown in this question. So just add a `.catch()` statement to all your `publishTrack` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That is weird that you can't seem to catch the error. I'm not sure I have an answer for that.

However, you could check whether the local participant is connected before trying to disconnect them. A [`Participant` object has a `state` property](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.18.2/docs/Participant.html) that can be "connected", "disconnected" or "failed".

So, you could:

```
if (this.activeRoom && this.activeRoom.localParticipant.state === 'connected') {
  this.activeRoom.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, didnt work as you can see in my updated question

Comment: Hmmm. I'm going to have to go try to reproduce this and see what I can come up with. Sorry!

Comment: it looks like the issue went away altogether when i upgraded from twilio version 1.8.0 to 1.8.2(no more unexpected disconnects). However i'm still unsure why I was unable to catch random disconnect errors. this makes me think that this problem may arise in future again, Thanks for all the help

Comment: It was likely a bug internally with an uncaught promise. Glad updating fixed it for you. If it happens again, I recommend reporting it to Twilio support as that’s not the correct behaviour obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to solve this issue

```
(new Promise(() => room.disconnect())).then(() => {}).catch(() => {})
```

Comment: in my case, this happens when disconnect when room connecting